# How to force a decimal point using Java DecimalFormat?

Tags: java, decimalformat

I have this code with two doubles:

```
double a = 2000.01;
double b = 2000.00;
String pattern = "0.##";
DecimalFormat dc = new DecimalFormat(pattern); // <- "0.##" does not work
System.out.println(dc.format(a));
System.out.println(dc.format(b));
```

Need to a pattern that would produce the following output:

```
2000.01
2000.
```

The decimal point is present for **b** even though zeros are not printed

Comment: Why would you want it to print `2000.`? That's not even a number anymore.

Comment: This is for a feed into an external system. They do not accept trailing zeros and do not accept flat numbers without decimal points.

Comment: Given the two doubles in my example they would accept the strings that I have printed. It is not for me to change their acceptance criteria.

And the string "2000." ends with a dot, not a zero.

Comment: Hold up - do you want a `.00` for an integer or not? Because your existing code seems to work just fine if so. Really - your question asked to force a decimal point, so I based the pattern off of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use 'DecimalFormat.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown' to always include the decimal.

Sample:

```
double a = 2000.01;
double b = 2000.00;
String pattern = "0.##";
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
df.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(true);
System.out.println(df.format(a));
System.out.println(df.format(b));
```

Sample Output:

```
2000.01
2000.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern: `#0.00`

It should look like this:

```
double a = 2000.01;
double b = 2000.00;
String pattern = "#0.00";
DecimalFormat dc = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
System.out.println(dc.format(a));
System.out.println(dc.format(b));
```

Which prints:

```
2000.01
2000.00
```

Comment: That's *not* the format that's requested though. The OP wants the second value to be formatted as "2000.00". From the question: "The decimal point is present for b even though zeros are not printed"

Answer (score 0):

extend DecimalFormat

```
public class MDF extends DecimalFormat {
  public String format(double d) {
    String s = super.format(d);
    if (!s.contains(".")) {
      return s + ".";
    }
    return s;
  }
}
```

Comment: This would work. However, there is a ```DecimalFormat.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown``` setter that does the job directly. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63943921/270576